# Apps Script Data entry Form - Running total stopped working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can't get the script to update the running total.  Been trying for a week, cant see whats wrong.  see below.

Data entry form is - shUserForm
Data sheet is dependant upon entry in shUserForm E5

The new running total = the old running total is, Data sheet lastRow (blankRow-1)'L') pluss of shUser E17 and minus E15, show result in blankRow 'L'.

```
function submitData(){
  try {
    let myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("TRANSACTIONS");
    let shAccount=shUserForm.getRange("E5").getValue();
    let datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName(shAccount);
    let blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1;
    let shUserFormValues = shUserForm.getRange(5,5,17,1).getValues();
    let dataSheetValues = [];  // [[E5],[E7],[E9],[E11],[E13],[E19]
    for( let i=0; i<13; i+=2 ) {
      dataSheetValues.push(shUserFormValues[i][0]); // E5 to E17
    }
    
    
    dataSheetValues.push(shUserFormValues[14][0]); // E19

    //code to update the data in datasheet

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2,1,8).setValues([dataSheetValues]);

    //To add date and time of entry

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow,10).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm');

    //To add 'Submitted by' to row 11 (K)

    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 11).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); 

    //To calculate new running total
```

```
let previousValue = dataSheet.getRange(blankRow-1,12).getValue();
let runningTotal = previousValue+shUserFormValues[13][0]-shUserFormValues[11][0];
datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(runningTotal);
```

```
    //To clear form data after submission

    shUserForm.getRange("E5").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E7").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E9").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E11").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E13").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E15").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E17").clear();
    shUserForm.getRange("E19").clear();

  
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

Tried adding formula, not certain that was done right.  Tried adding the running total script above the submit script.  Probably something simple but I am stil learning.

Comment: It's time to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: `dataSheetValues.push(shUserFormValues[14][0]);` shUserFormValues doesn't have a [14] last one is 12. It's range is 0-12